# Sort collection by property, given as a String

Tags: java, reflection, nashorn

I'm implementing server side processing for jQuery datatables. For those of you who are unfamiliar with it, the plugin allows you to sort a column asc/desc, as well as search all columns with a single textbox. Since my list of objects is too large to send to the client, i need to replicate it's sorting functionality thru Java.

This is the object that i'm working with. Each field is a column in the client side table. All fields are either Strings or primitives/wrappers.

```
public class MyObject{

    String id;
    String productType;
    String productGroup;

    double totalSales;
    double salesVariance;

    int vendorId;
    String vendorName;
}
```

I need to be able to sort by any of the fields, ascending/descending, WITHOUT hard coding a comparator function for each field.

Given a string that represents a field name, how would I implement a generic sorting function?

My current solution is to process the list with Nashorn... :)

Java method that calls Nashorn:

```
/**
 * @param sortBy - field name
 * @param sortDirection - asc/desc
 */
public void applyFilteringChanges(List<MyObject> myObjects, String sortBy, String sortDirection) throws Exception{

    Invocable invocable = (Invocable) engine;
    invocable.invokeFunction("sortObjects", myObjects, sortBy, sortDirection);

}
```

Nashorn code:

```
function sortObjects(myObjects, prop, direction) {
    var dir = (direction === 'asc') ? 1 : -1;
    myObjects.sort(function(a,b){
        return compare(a,b,prop) * dir;
    })
};

function compare(a,b,prop){
    if(a[prop] < b[prop])
        return -1;
    else if(a[prop] > b[prop])
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

I also dabbled in Reflection, but it's incomplete at the moment.

```
public void applyFilteringChanges(List<MyObject> myObjects, String sortBy, String sortDirection) throws Exception{

        myObjects.sort((s1,s2)->{
            Field field;
            try {
                field = s1.getClass().getDeclaredField(sortBy);
                Class<?> type = field.getType();
                if(type.isPrimitive()){
                    //deal with primitive
                }else{
                    Comparable o1FieldValue = (Comparable) field.get(s1);
                    Comparable o2FieldValue = (Comparable) field.get(s2);
                    return o1FieldValue.compareTo(o2FieldValue);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return 0;
        });

    }
```

Both of my approaches feel like hacks, is there a standard way to accomplish this?

Comment: Sorting an object by any property without providing comparators for those properties bascially leaves you with those options, i.e. either using reflection in Java (you could use libraries to make using that easier) or convert the objects into another representation (e.g. JSON for use with Nashorn, a map etc.) and then sort that. One note though: I'd not call the reflection code on every `compare()` call but once before actually sorting - at least the retrieval of the field.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a generic Comparator like this :

```
class MyComparator<T extends MyObject> implements Comparator<T> {

    private String field;

    public MyComparator(String field) {
        this.field = field;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(T o1, T o2) {
        switch (field) {
            case "id" :
                return o1.id.compareTo(o2.id);

            case "productType":
                return o1.productType.compareTo(o2.productType);

            case "productGroup":
                return o1.productGroup.compareTo(o2.productGroup);

            //...
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Use it like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    List<MyObject> objects = new ArrayList<>();

    Collections.sort(objects, new MyComparator<>("id"));
}
```

Comment: That sort of violates the request for doing it "WITHOUT hard coding a comparator function for each field."

Comment: Yes but as a part of his question is "how would I implement a generic sorting function"